# How to save sessionId in express between requests?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

I'm have an app which i make 3 requests from the client to the server.

Each call i need to use data that i get from the `WS` .

So i want to store some data in the server and don't return it to the client.

How can set my `sessionID` do be associated in the express server do the client request?

Now my `sessionID` restart every request that i make to the server...

I use `reverseProxy` to run my express server using `pm2` .

My client and my server run on `HTTPS`

My session config look like this :

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1)
app.use(session({
     proxy:true,
     resave:true,
     secret: process.env.SECRET,
     cookie: {secure : true, maxAge : 8 * 60 * 60 *1000,sameSite: "none", httpOnly:false},
     credentials:true,
     saveUninitialized:true,

})
)
```

Comment: Are your frontend and backend on different domains perhaps? Then the session cookie might be blocked by your browser as a third-party cookie.

Comment: Yes, both on the same domain

Comment: Can you check in your browser's devtools whether (a) the session cookie is sent in the reponse (b) whether the browser stores the cookie (in Chrome, this is "Application > Storage > Cookies")?

Comment: When i open this => Application > Storage > Cookies , i see in the name col only connect.sid

Comment: That's the session cookie. It should be sent back to your backend with the next request and `req.session` should be automatically filled in your backend code. You speak of a `sessionID`, where does that appear in your code?

Comment: How can i send it to the client?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Please give more details in your question (rather than in comments).

Comment: How can i send the connect.sid cookie from the client to the sever?

Comment: The browser sends it automatically, you cannot influence this.

Comment: Yes, sorry, given the information in your question, I cannot see why the browser would not send back the cookie. Perhaps share details from the network trace about the requests your browser makes.